# Thunderbird cannot be closed, but no process running

Tags: thunderbird, process

I have a problem where Thunderbird cannot be closed and no interaction is possible.  Only the context menu sometimes appears on the left upper corner of the screen.

No Thunderbird related process is running based on system information.

System information:

- Ubuntu 21.10
- Gnome Version 40.4.0
- Hewlett-Packard HP EliteBook 850 G1
- Thunderbird: 91.3.1 (64-Bit)

I am quite new to Ubuntu.  If any additional information is needed to figure out the problem please let me know what and how I can provide it.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem; the only way that I've found to fix it so far is to log out and log back in again.